# How to sort a list of lists using a sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, mysql-8.0

## Abstract question

I have a sql-table that contains records in the following form:
`(list_id, value)` where the `list_id` is an Integer identifiing a specific list and the `value` is something that has an order.

I now struggle to write a sql query that returns all records of that table at first ordered by the rank the list has compared to the other lists and then ordered by the `value`.

The abstract problem is, that I want to sort a list of lists using sql.

### Algorithm to compare two lists

The algorithm to compare two lists is the following:

```hs
data CompareRes = FirstSmaller | FirstGreater | Equal deriving Show

compareLists :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> CompareRes
compareLists [] [] = Equal
-- Longer lists are considered to be smaller
compareLists _ [] = FirstSmaller
compareLists [] _ = FirstGreater
compareLists (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | x < y = FirstSmaller
  | x > y = FirstGreater
  | otherwise = compareLists xs ys
```

## Details

In my specific case the values are all `Date`s.
So my table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `list_date` (
  `list_id` INT  NOT NULL,
  `date`    DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`list_id`, `date`)
);
```

I'm using a mysql:8.0 database so a solution using `WINDOW`-functions is acceptable.

## Example

### Data

```sql
INSERT INTO `list_date` VALUES
   (1, '2019-11-02'), (1, '2019-11-03'), (1, '2019-11-04'), (1, '2019-11-05'), (1, '2019-11-07'), (1, '2019-11-08'), (1, '2019-11-09'),
   (2, '2019-11-01'), (2, '2019-11-03'), (2, '2019-11-04'),
   (3, '2019-11-01'), (3, '2019-11-02'), (3, '2019-11-03'),
   (4, '2019-11-02'), (4, '2019-11-04'), (4, '2019-11-13'), (4, '2019-11-14'),
   (5, '2019-11-03'), (5, '2019-11-04'), (5, '2019-11-05'), (5, '2019-11-10'),
   (6, '2019-11-01'), (6, '2019-11-02'), (6, '2019-11-03'), (6, '2019-11-05');
```

### Query

Where I really struggle is to create an expression that calculates the `list_rank`:

```sql
SELECT 
    `list_id`, 
    `date`,
    <PLEASE HELP> as `list_rank`
FROM 
    `list_date`
ORDER BY 
    `list_rank`, `date`;
```

### Expected result

```
| list_id | date       | list_rank |
|---------|------------|-----------|
| 6       | 2019-11-01 | 1         |
| 6       | 2019-11-02 | 1         |
| 6       | 2019-11-03 | 1         |
| 6       | 2019-11-05 | 1         |
| 3       | 2019-11-01 | 2         |
| 3       | 2019-11-02 | 2         |
| 3       | 2019-11-03 | 2         |
| 2       | 2019-11-01 | 3         |
| 2       | 2019-11-03 | 3         |
| 2       | 2019-11-04 | 3         |
| 1       | 2019-11-02 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-03 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-04 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-05 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-07 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-08 | 4         |
| 1       | 2019-11-09 | 4         |
| 4       | 2019-11-02 | 5         |
| 4       | 2019-11-04 | 5         |
| 4       | 2019-11-13 | 5         |
| 4       | 2019-11-14 | 5         |
| 5       | 2019-11-03 | 6         |
| 5       | 2019-11-04 | 6         |
| 5       | 2019-11-05 | 6         |
| 5       | 2019-11-10 | 6         |
```

or

[image: visual representation of the expected result]

That image is the current live result my application produces. Currently the sorting is implemented using Java.

## Edit

After not receiving a better answer, I implemented a solution as suggested by @gordon-linoff:

```sql
SELECT 
    `list_id`, 
    `date`
FROM 
    `list_date`
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT `sub`.`list_id`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(`sub`.`date` ORDER BY `sub`.`date` SEPARATOR '')  as `concat_dates`
            FROM `list_date` as `sub`
            GROUP BY `sub`.`list_id`
        ) `all_dates` ON (`all_dates`.`list_id` = `list_date`.`list_id`)
ORDER BY 
    `all_dates`.`concat_dates`, `date`;
```

I've also created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b19152/4) - So you can play around with your solution.

But this solution does not sort the lists as expected because longer lists are considered bigger than smaller lists.

So I am still hoping to receive a solution that solves 100% of my requirements :)

Comment: i can't see what your ranking is based on. why is 6 the lowest rank?

Comment: @nbk: I edited the question so that it clearifies that when two lists get compared and one list starts with all elements of the second list, the list with more elements should be considered smaller.

Comment: Your List has no characteristig to sort or give a ranking number to a specific list_id. You have to provide a basic idea an algorithm how to do it. like i said in my first comment, nothing is clear till now. you have to explain how list_id 1 has the ranking 4

Comment: @nbk Thank you for clarifying. I added a specification for the comparison function in haskell. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can sort the lists by the dates concatenated together:

```
select ld.*
from list_date ld join
     (select list_id, group_concat(date) as dates
      from ld
      group by list_id
     ) ldc
     on ld.list_id = ldc.list_id
order by ldc.dates, ld.date;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer - It really helps a lot :) There is one minor problem left: As you can see in my example result, longer lists should appear on top. When I use the query you have provided it returns list `3` before list `6`. Do you also have an idea how I could change that?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's for MySql 8 the window functions can be used for this (yay).

Here's a query that first calculates some metrics, to use in the calculation of the ranking:

```
SELECT 
 list_id, 
 `date`,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ListMinDate ASC, ListCount DESC, ListMaxDate, list_id) AS list_rank
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   list_id,
   `date`,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY list_id) AS ListCount,
   MIN(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY list_id) AS ListMinDate,
   MAX(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY list_id) AS ListMaxDate
  FROM list_date
) q
ORDER BY list_rank, `date`
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8ef7d7358b03b4c11ae55c06d0d726a)*

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer. But because it just sorts the lists by their min elements, their max elements and thier sizes, your query incorrectly sorts lists with the same number of elements and the same min and max element. For example the two lists: `[1,3,4]` and `[1,2,4]` will incorrectly be sorted in the order they got inserted (expected output: `[[1,2,4], [1,3,4]]`). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39706745e4c9bdbb4d4b9d2abe8f0bd1)

Comment: @JonasTaulien Database tables contain unordered sets.  If the table had something like an ID that's filled via [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp) ,or the datetime when the record was created,then it would be possible to sort the rank on the lowest ID of a set.  But based on that example one can't know which were inserted first.  If there's such ID then it would be possible to calculate a MIN OVER for it, and use that in the DENSE_RANK.

Comment: I must admit, that I do not understand how an `id` or an `created_at` column would help by sorting the lists according to the algorithm I have specified in my question. Can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: It's just that there's no guarantee that a SELECT on a table without an ORDER BY will return the records in the exact same order as they were inserted.  So if one needs the order in which they were inserted, then one needs some field that can  be used for that.  And the values for the current 3 fields apperentally can be inserted in any order.